# Interfacing RFID with STM32

Tags: hex, stm32, uart, rfid, stm32cubeide

I am trying to interface an YHY502CTG RFID reader module with an STM32H7A3ZITQ using STM32CubeIDE. But I am not able to set the interaction between the host and the module. Could someone please help me with it's hardware connection and the hex commands related to the code?

I was trying to set UART communication between STM32 board and YHY502CTG reader module.

Here is my code:

```c
uint8_t CMD[]={0XAA,0XBB,0X03,0X14,0X13,0X04}; // command for reading module type
uint8_t RxData[30];//will store response

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, CMD, sizeof(CMD), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(1000);
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart4, RxData, sizeof(RxData), HAL_Max_Delay);
HAL_Delay(1000);
```

Comment: I presume you've looked at [the datasheet](https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DS_YHY502CTGV33_datasheet.pdf)? It seems to describe the protocol fairly well, and it is just a simple UART interface. Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I wrote the code using HAL_UART_Transmit and HAL_UART_Receive for transmitting hex commands to the reader module but it is not working.

Comment: Probably you should [edit] your question to include the relevant code, along with a description of what your actual symptoms are. "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful.

Comment: uint8_t CMD[]={0XAA,0XBB,0X03,0X14,0X13,0X04};// command for reading module type
uint8_t RxData[30];//will store response


 
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, CMD, sizeof(CMD), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
 
 
     HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart4, RxData, sizeof(RxData), HAL_Max_Delay);


         HAL_Delay(1000);// this is the code I have written on cubeide,I also tried interfacing it with arduino but still the reader module is not sending the response

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the [datasheet](https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DS_YHY502CTGV33_datasheet.pdf) for the YHY502CTG that indicates that you need to wait for 1000ms before it will send a reply. The implication is that it will send a reply immediately.

Therefore, remove the delay between your transmit and receive.

Note that the STM32 does not have some kind of internal buffer that can store received UART characters until you choose to read them. If the RFID module sends a response while you are delaying (as seems likely), the response will just be lost completely.

The datasheet also suggests that command 0x01 should be used to read the module type, whereas you are using command 0x14. So either your array, or the comment on it, or both, are wrong. Command 0x14 is a "Beep" command.

[image]

Comment: I removed the delay  and changed the command but still there is no response sent to the controller by the reader module

Comment: I'd suggest getting an oscilloscope or logic analyser hooked up to the UART tx/rx signals and see what that looks like. We also have no idea how you have connected the two boards together.